# Problems with color management in Firefox 3.6 on MacOS

Tags: macos, firefox, color-profiles

I cannot seem to find a color profile for the latest Firefox, MacOS 10.5, that results in accurate color. The color that I see in Adobe CS, the finder, and Safari is accurate. The color I see in Firefox is not.

I am currently using Huey Pro for color calibration. However, this problem predates the Huey. I was hoping the Huey would solve the problem, but it has not made it any better. Using the Color Management plugin, if I select the profile generated by Huey Pro, the color is way too dark and oversaturated. If I use the default monitor profile, the color is better in terms of brightness, but way off in terms of hue and saturation.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't the answer you want to hear, but I think its probably a good thing that you don't have "accurate color" in at least one of your browsers. The range in colors that people will see varies between computers/monitors/operating systems/browsers. You kind of have to give up on having *perfect* color when you're making a website. If your design fails because you don't have the right color profile, you need a new design. Even if you find a way to get firefox to have perfect color by getting some kind of color profile for it, the end users of the website will not.

Comment: This is a fair point. I have other web browsers and OS to check color. With Firefox, it's really an enjoyment problem for me. Firefox is my favorite browser, and I don't like having to leave it because I want to look at photos on Flickr without them appearing dark and oversaturated. Maybe I should just migrate to a different browser. I was hoping for another option.

Comment: Interesting idea. This is basically the same concept behind "studio monitors" or "reference monitors", which are essentially speakers used by recording studios to emulate low-end consumer audio equipment. The idea was that if they used this as their base reference for mixing and mastering, they could make the album sound good on the widest range of audio equipment, including cheap audio speakers and portable players.

Comment: I have had clients insist that I make designs look good on their monitors. When I explained to them (in more common terms than these) that their monitor was not a good baseline to calibrate for, the response was: It has to look right on my monitor. Other people probably have monitors like mine. Ultimately, it's up to the client. Yes, it is a lot like reference monitors. I'm also a bit of an audiophile.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `gfx.color_management.enabled` in `about:config` or this [color management addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/color-management)?

Comment: Yes. They both do the same thing. Prior to Firefox 3.6, I had accurate color using either of these (which do the same thing - one with a GUI and the other without).

Comment: Here's a list of the [color management preferences in Firefox 3+](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/ICC_color_correction_in_Firefox).

Comment: The closest I have been able to get is using the AdobeRGB1998 Colorsync profile. Using WideAngleRGB as a bit too desaturated. It's not exactly the same as Photoshop and Safari, but it's close enough for jazz.